# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when checking an operation queue for duplicates

Tags: objective-c, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I have an NSOperationQueue in my app that handles endpoint URL requests. To avoid adding duplicate requests, wherever possible I check the queue to see whether this endpoint call is already handled.

For some reason, generally only when the endpoint operation queue is getting spammed like hell, but also randomly at other times (implying to me that it's a very uncommon race condition of some sort), I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS when scanning my operation queue for duplicates. It happens on the line:

```
 if (![endpointOperation.urlRequest respondsToSelector: @selector(URL)]) {
```

Here's the code:

```
-(BOOL)operationQueueContainsDuplicateOperations
{
    for (EndpointOperation *endpointOperation in [EndpointOperationQueueManager instance].operationQueue.operations) {

        if (![endpointOperation.urlRequest respondsToSelector: @selector(URL)]) {
            return NO;
        }

        if (![self.urlRequest respondsToSelector: @selector(URL)]) {
            return NO;
        }

        if ([[endpointOperation.urlRequest.URL absoluteString] isEqualToString:[self.urlRequest.URL absoluteString]] &&
            (self.relatedProfileIds && [endpointOperation.relatedProfileIds isEqualToArray:self.relatedProfileIds])) {

            return YES;
        }
    }

    return NO;
```

}

I thought maybe the operation queue was being modified while this loop was in process but I don't know how that would happen - and when I receive the crash, I can view the contents of the relevant objects and they look fine. Any ideas?

Comment: I would set a breakpoint on Objective-C exceptions and hope for a better error message than EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: My guess is that you can't iterate the array on the queue because you'll end in a race condition issue (also the enumerator will be constantly changing it's pointer due the re-sort of the array). Why don't keep a NSDictionary with the list of endpoints in the queue? (So you can search for the key). Also you can apply KVO to the operations array, so that would be a safer approach :)